# find angle sine knowing all sides

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

I know all the sides of an arbitrary triangle but not the angles, and I want to find the sine of any angle.

```
       A
       ^
     b/ \c
     /   \
   C/_____\B
       a
```

I know that $\cos(C)=\frac{a²+b²-c²}{2ab}$ (where side 'c' is opposite to angle 'C').
I want a similar one for sin
The only thing I got is $\sin(C) = \sqrt{1-\cos^2(C)}$ I want a simpler one .. does it exist?

Comment: When only three sides are known, sine law does not apply. What you have done is correct already. Another way is to find out what C is by cosine law, and then find sin C directly via calculator.

Comment: That's not "Another way" it's the way i already mentioned

Comment: define simpler..  You can plug the `cos` expression into the `sqrt` form, so have a single exprecion without the intermediate `cos` calculation.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13039/164803

Comment: @Szabolcs I'm not saying I'm him, i just think it's fun to use his name & photo

Answer (score 1):

We know that $c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab \cos{C}$, and you know $a$, $b$, and $c$, so plug it in and find out the $\cos$ of that angle. If you want to find the sine, just use any conversion formula, such as $\sin{x}^2+\cos{x}^2=1$ or any other conversion necessary. This is the simplest way. Darya's answer is just as valid, but just takes more steps and calculates unnecessary information.

Also I just want to say that its been an honor helping the President with his geometry work.

Comment: "an honor helping the President" -- put that on your resume!

Comment: @george sadly I feel that this might not be a verifiable president-helping session as it could be some ruffian pretending he's the president to get preferential help. I know that no patriotic American would ever do that, and those outside of the USA respect him enough to give him space, but because I dont have verification, i'm not sure my future employers would believe it.

Comment: I only used it because it's fun dear ordinary citizen. nothing else.

Comment: And please stop repeating the method i mentioned in the question as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I read only the problem, and quickly deduced the simplest way to do it, and answered before I saw your work, presuming that your work had reached no avail, and you just wanted any method. After looking back I realized my mistake, but let my answer stand as it is the simplest method, and I don't believe can be improved upon.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
you can find area of triangle . then you can find sin A by using the formulas below

Comment: You sir made it more complicated than the one i already have

Comment: His way works, but it is a bit over-complicated and calculates more than required, like the semi-perimeter (p) and the area (S)

Comment: @Asimov I know it works, but I've already mentioned a simpler method and asked for simpler .. so this isn't really helpful

Comment: @Barack If simpler doesnt exist then will you accept no answer and give no one recognition for their thoughts and efforts?

Comment: I appreciate every effort of help, and if no way already exists, i will figure-out one

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the simplest form:

$\frac{sin A}{a}=\frac{sin B}{b}=\frac{sin C}{c}=\frac{1}{2 a b c } \sqrt{(a^2+b^2+c^2)^2-2(a^4+b^4+c^4)}$

Comment: Did you read the question? or even the title?

Comment: do i need to break that into three expressions?

Comment: No thank you...